# log scale boxplots in R

Tags: r

For the plots I'm trying to generate, I want to apply log scale to the y axis.

The original code is

```
bxp(confSum, main="Mean Coverage Per Exon for Hiseq", ylab="Fold Coverage", 
    las=2, cex.lab=1, cex.axis=0.7,xaxt='n', ann=FALSE)
```

which works fine but not in log scale.

Based on some information online, I added `log="y"` to the code, and the pdf it produces just become empty with nothing on it...

Did I make a mistake somewhere?.. How should I fix it for log scale?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
> boxplot(decrease ~ treatment, data = OrchardSprays,
+         log = "y", col = "bisque")
```

Comment: Sorry bear with me I'm new to R...can I somehow modify the original the old script for log scale?..

Comment: @JJS bxp is called by `boxplot` to actually render the plot I think so you should be able to achieve the same with `bxp`. I saw in the documentation `?bxp` the the `log` parameter is available. Does it show the plot in `R`? Probably the issue is only the `pdf` creation.

Comment: Yeah..I don't really know if it's just simply add log = "y" to bxp, but I figured it out by adding log when pass in the data. Thx. :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I figured out it was because my dataset had some zero values, so I substituted them for NA and it worked out. It's because boxplot function can't handle plotting the 0 values in the log scale (converges to infinite).